# How a register shifts information to right at positive egde of clock

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, flipflop, shift-register

We have given the following question:

**Design a 4-bit, shift-right register with D flip flops, and use two of these registers to implement a circuit that detects the sequence (x1,x0)=3,0,2,1 (the rightmost digit, "1" in this case, is the first going in, see example). Information shifts one position right each time a positive edge of CK arrives.**

I know how a shift register works, but this thing `Information shifts one position right each time a positive edge of CK arrives` is confusing me a lot. I do not understand how can we implement a shift-register that shifts the information to right at positive edge of a clock.

***MY ATTEMPT:***

I have made the following circuit which is wrong:
[image]

I would be really thankful if someone would help me out and tell me if I a missing something or if I am wrong anywhere. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: **contradiction in terminis**: I know how a shift register works, but this thing *Information shifts one position right each time a positive edge of CK arrives* is confusing me a lot. That *is the basic* of how a shift register works.

Comment: how did you confirm that this ckt is wrong ?

Comment: I am also totally lost in ---> I know how a shift register works, but this thing Information shifts one position right each time a positive edge of CK arrives is confusing me a lot <---- Thats what a shift register does ofcourse.

Comment: Which is your Most Significant Bit ? x1 or x0?

Comment: @MITURAJ I confirmed it by the software provided  to us. I made this circuit and when I checked my answer the software told 'The circuit behavior is wrong nad is not similar to the correct one'.

Comment: @MITURAJ and @oldfart yes I know that a shift-register is used to shift the bits to left or right or bi-directional or in cyclic way. But this thing `each time a positive edge of CK arrives`. How do we do this? How do we make it shift the bits only on positive edge of a clock in circuit implementation?

Comment: But that's why flip flops are there in shift register. It responds to its input on positive clock edge only.

Comment: @MITURAJ then why software is declaring my solution as wrong?

Comment: see if my answer helps.

Comment: It almost seems as though your question is how basic clocked logic works. You should maybe study the design of what is called a "flip flop" first. The wikipedia page may help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)

Comment: @mkeith I already know that how a flip flop works, I even know the working of different types of flip flops. I was just confused with the statement, but it is cleared now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence to be detected is (**x1**,**x0**)= 3,0,2,1. **x1** is MSB, **x0** is LSB. The output should therefore be triggered '1', when the four Flip-Flops are in the state:

> x1 : 1 0 1 0
>
> x0 : 1 0 0 1

But in your circuit, things are reversed. You have implemented it as **x1** = LSB and **x0** = MSB. Rest of the circuit looks fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MITU RAJ. Yes after seeing your solution, I realized that I have swapped the inputs. Thank you so much.